# Check the URL visited by other software

Tags: windows-10, url, event-log

In web browsers, I can check the URL I've visited through history page.

What if I want to check the URL visited by specific software in my Windows 10 computer?

For example I opened a software or UWA and this app made a request to certain URL, and I want that URL.

I think it is possible since I am using home network and I can check the network data.

I am using Windows 10 computer and my router is TP-LINK ac1350. No proxy server

Maybe is there a log recording all these data?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to know immediately what an application is accessing, then its pretty easy to do.  Download [Telerik Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/download/fiddler) and install it.  Then run it.  It logs all the HTTP requests, as seen below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a lot harder then you may imagine - it involves setting up a man-in-the-middle attack (normally by transparent proxying requests on the router) and configuring logging on the router.

In addition, for HTTPS you would need to install trusted keys and subvert the https security layer.

There is no log of this information kept anywhere, except probably on the server - if it's only 1 site you could probably recover information from the server log if you have access to it.